# Use Google Apps as a Domain Controller

Tags: cloud, google-apps, domaincontroller

Is it possible to use google apps as a domain controller. Specifically I want to remove our local dependence on a local windows DC. I want to have it so that users sit down at their workstations and when they log in they are authenticated against google apps user directory. I have yet to figure out how to piece together printer/etc sharing, but the org is currently using google apps for email, contacts, and calender... and box as a file server. The goal is to move us to 100% cloud then write up a case study on the whole affair.

Comment: This is definitely for serverfault

Comment: Thanks, I have posted it there. I did not know that serverfault existed. Should I close this question somehow?

Comment: I appreciated this question was closed.. I ASKED FOR IT TO BE, but getting a -1 was completely inappropriate! Lets try to motivate people positively rather than create a sense of exclusion or aristocracy... especially when the question has been moved to a sister community.. that behavior should be encouraged and even REWARDED!! I am going to see if I can propose an election to elect a site ombudsman.